# How to set lazy loading on datalist in meteor. Can i get an example?

Tags: meteor

i m using meteor for developing app . I need to set lazy loading in my datalist with limit data show is 5 . Can i get an example so that i can put lazy loading in datalist in meteor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by lazy loading?  It's not clear to me what you are wanting specifically.

Comment: I want something like when i scroll down my list which i got on datalist , the data will be loaded as scroll goes down.

Comment: See this URL , This provide infinite scrolling with limited data shown in list. I saw this example but i didn't get it that how it will be used in our .js file. https://atmospherejs.com/staringatlights/infinite-scroll

Comment: Yes, i would use a package such as this as it's somewhat complex to roll your own infinite scroll. To use this package you need to put your data list in its own template, initialize infinite scroll in the template's `onCreated` callback and create a publication on the server for your data list data. Basically follow the example but instead of "comments" it would be your data list data.

Comment: that means , example will be same , all i need to do is instead of "commemts " .  I should put my collection?

Comment: For example, you would use your collection (instead of Comments) in the publication function. And instead of a Comments template, you would have a different template named after what your data is and it  would iterate over your data instead. Basically, use the same structure as the example but change it for your specifics.

Comment: ok, i will . Thanks :)

Comment: Any easy pagination is there? becoz its not working . May be i am not getting it how to use but i tried and it didn't worked.

Comment: Search atmosphere js, there are tons of pagination options, or search google, there are many meteor pagination tutorials too.

Comment: @jordanwillis  I have seen some infinite scrolling packages at atmosphere but i didn't get. As i am new to this technology i didn't understand how to use it. Please give me one example with simple explanation so that i can follow it and use infinite scrolling .